# "Choose production" bug: game stops map scrolling and doesn't respond to orders, but shows tooltips and animations

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

There is an annoying bug in Civilization 5: Brave New World, when in certain conditions game stops responding to your orders: you cannot move units, switch between them or choose their actions. However, the game doesn't hang up - it still shows animations, shows tooltips for terrain tiles while hovering the cursor, the menu can be shown and the game could be saved/loaded in this state.

Reloading the saved game during this "limbo" state results in an infinite rotating globe cursor loop. However, loading the bugged saved game after killing and restarting the games loads fine and the game can be resumed.

This bug happens frequently during the production changing for the city, so it's widely called the "Choose production bug". But it also happens when you use the ranged attack, found religion, switch between units. Validating the game doesn't show any problems.
Have anyone got rid of this bug?

EDIT1: If I exit the game in that "limbo" state, I notice that the game executable still resides in memory, playing music. Is this a kind of a sign that the bug is related to the multimedia issue?

EDIT2: The saved game immediately before the bug (after the caravel move) is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/1p859xbfhifgue3/6.Civ5Save

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It sounds like you already have a workaround (restart the game). A fix probably needs to come from the game developer.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Restarting the game isn't a good workaround: you'll lose all progress since your last save. I've hit this bug, and discovered that if I save the game after the bug appears, then loading the game will *still* have the same bug, requiring me to backtrack.

Comment: Are you using any mods? I've never hit this bug, and I play with a few mods in various combinations: Info Addict, Communitas, Fast Aircraft Animation, Colored Religions, and More Resources.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals No mods, nothing, just pure installation with BNW DLC installed over the vanilla.

Comment: @DavidHarkness : There were no mods installed

Comment: You've probably already tried this, but does hitting `Esc` close the **Choose Production** popup?

Comment: The game doesn't exactly stops at a popup. It stops responding at the moment right before the popup is going to be activated.

Comment: @DavidHarkness I've updated the question, providing a link to a saved game.

Comment: Did you try clicking on the city and choosing a production?

Comment: what is it that 2k recommended that didn't work (so that you don't just get the same suggestion here)?

Comment: Does [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/153248/23) help?

Comment: @TZHX They recommendations were usual: have you tried to turn it off and on again, did you update your video drivers etc.

Comment: However, there are several ones that seem reasonable and I didn't try: run as admin, run with all startup items disabled. Also disabling  multithreading is worth trying.

Comment: @badp Havent tried it yet, but going to once I arrive home. I think that idea is promising since the bug environment indeed reminds of a multithreading lock-up issue. I remember such kind of lock-ups in Left4Dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to their website, and they had a link that talked about bugs that can't make the player end the turn, they told me to go into, my documents library  then find the my games folder and find Sid Meier's Civilization 5 folder and locate config.ini in the folder and change:

```
EnableGameCoreThreading = 1
```

to

```
EnableGameCoreThreading = 0
```

Afterwards, I went back into the game and started up a new game and went it finally loaded it still wouldn't work. I don't know if I did it right or not. I tried uninstalling all my mods I have downloaded off the steam workshop, and even the game itself, and still no dice.

Comment: I think this is it! Changed to zero, played for a few hours, not a single bug!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds rather similar what I've seen before. You get tool tips, game renders fine, but you have problems selecting objects.
Try hitting the escape key. I recall that revived it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help.

Comment: Being more specific - hitting `Esc` bgings up game menu and nothing more.

Comment: What I remembered is that when I get the tool tip, game renders, but you can't go into cities, select units, perform actions, etc etc, if you go and hit escape, it exited that state and I could start select units perform actions again.

Comment: I checked it again - if I press `Esc`, a game menu appears, but the game state doesn't change. However I noticed that the limbo state now can happen during almost any game event - policy adopting, diplomacy negotiation etc.

Comment: @mbaitoff bummer that sucks. I haven't seen it that often myself... :( Sorry that didn't help